# Font awesome shows Squares until it is loaded

Tags: http, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome like so:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxx.js"></script>
```

and an element

However the font doesn't load immediately, and I see ugly squares in the meantime before its loaded. Any way round this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing [FOUT (flash of unstyled text)](https://www.zachleat.com/web/webfont-glossary/#fout) as Font Awesome uses fonts to display their icons. Until the font is loaded you'll see the icon in a fallback font (for instance Arial). You see the box because Font Awesome uses [Unicode PUA codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) to map their icons to, and the fallback font has no characters there and will show the generic "missing character" box.

A solution would be to use [FontFaceObserver](https://fontfaceobserver.com/) to hide the icons until the Font Awesome font has loaded. Even better would be to use SVG images, as icon fonts are kind of a hack. Font Awesome provides them, so this might be an option for you.

Comment: hmm thats kinda sad that they do that